# Get a random value from a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

The way I get a value from a single dimensional array is:

```
Random random = new Random();
getit = w[r.Next(0, w.Length)];
```

Can you please tell me how do I do the same for two dimensional array?

Answer (score 8):

To ensure that you have an even distribution you shouldn't be generating multiple random numbers.  Calculate the total possible number of values by multiplying the lengths of the dimensions, choose an index, and then find the one item that corresponds to that index:

```
public static T GetRandomValue<T>(T[,] array, Random random)
{
    int values = array.GetLength(0) * array.GetLength(1);
    int index = random.Next(values);
    return array[index / array.GetLength(0), index % array.GetLength(0)];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a simple two-dimensional array `[,]`<sup>1</sup>, *not a jagged array `[][]`*, then you can use the [`Array.GetLength` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) to get the length of each array dimension. For example:

```
Random random = new Random();
string[,] arr = new string[10, 10];

int i1 = r.Next(0, arr.GetLength(0));
int i2 = r.Next(0, arr.GetLength(1));
string value = arr[i1, i2];
```

<sup>1</sup>) It is possible for the lower bound of a multi-dimensional array to be different from the default of 0. In that case, use the [`Array.GetLowerBound` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx) appropriately.

---

If you have a jagged array instead `[][]`, *not a real two-dimensional array `[,]`*, then you can do it sequentially:

```
Random random = new Random();
string[][] arr = new string[][10];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    arr[i] = new string[10];

int i1 = r.Next(0, arr.Length);
string[] subarr = arr[i1];
int i2 = r.Next(0, subarr.Length);
string value = subarr[i2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really the fastest method, but you could also do this with a bit of Linq:

```
var totalSize = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank).Aggregate(0, (l, r) => l * array.GetLength(r));
var getit = w.ElementAt(r.Next(0, totalSize));
```

This works for arrays of any dimension.

Comment: The problem here is that you turn it from O(1) to O(n), as you need to iterate the array to get to it.  Oh, and you want to use `First`, not `Take(1)`.  He'll want one item, not a sequence of size one.

Comment: @Servy I did say it wouldn't be the fastest method. I changed it to `ElementAt` which is O(1) for one-dimensional arrays at least.